# Slackware 14x86_64, gnome 3.6 and alps touchpad scrolling settings

Tags: gnome3, touchpad, slackware, scrolling

I have a Dell Latitude E6510 with Slackware 14x86_64, gnome 3.6 (dropline), alps dualpoint touchpad and the latest 3.11.4 kernel.
My touchpad is being detected correctly and I have the touchpad settings in the gnome settings but unfortunately the scrolling works only with two fingers. I am quite used to doing that with one finger. Is it still possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change that in Gnome's Control Center. Run `gnome-control-center` or choose settings from the menu. Then, go into the 'Mouse & Touchpad' section and switch to edge scrolling in the 'Touchpad' tab:

[image]

If that doesn't work, you can try and set it manually. Edit or create the file
`/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf` and make it look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option        "HorizEdgeScroll"    "1"
    Option        "MaxTapTime"        "300"
    Driver "synaptics"
EndSection
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the tab "Touchpad" in settings. I have some settings for the touchpad in the "Mouse" tab. The available options there are: Tap to click, Two finger scroll, Content sticks to fingers, Disable while typing. I guess I need to set the options into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` ?

Comment: @tftd could you add a screenshot? What if you just disable two finger scroll?

Comment: There you go http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3461/fqpk.png .Nothing happens when I disable the two finger scroll. I can still scroll with two fingers and can't scroll with one.

Comment: Perhaps you need to restart the trackpad driver somehow for the settings to take effect. Try rebooting just in case. If that doesn't work, yes, you'll have to  do it manually. See updated answer.

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it's not working as well. I'm not sure if that file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf` is being loaded. How could I check that?

Comment: @tftd if it's there, it should be loaded. You may have to tweak the details a bit. That one worked for me on an old laptop but it was a while ago.

Comment: Actually after adding `Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"` everything started working just fine. Thank you very much for your help!